# Changing the prototype of an object on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototype-programming

Is it possible to change the prototype of an object in IE? Chrome and Firefox support the `__proto__` attribute for this, but IE doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not allow the prototype of an object to be changed. `__proto__` is not a standard property and you should not rely on it.

In general you should use [getProtoTypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to get the prototype of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just setting the prototype like so:

```
function Vehicle(tires) {
    this.tires = tires;
}

function Car(doors) {
    this.doors = doors;
}

Car.prototype = new Vehicle(4);

function Coupe(seats) {
    this.seats = seats
}

Coupe.prototype = new Car(2);
```